# datetime2 does not respect polyglossia language settings (using lualatex)

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, datetime2

`datetime2` does not automatically deduces the correct language from the `polyglossia` settings. If you set the date style by hand, it works. (`datetime2-german` is installed.)

I'm using lualatex (this might be relevant):

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)
```

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\begin{document}
    \today

    \DTMsetdatestyle{german}
    \today
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

The `datetime2` docu reads:

> If you want to use datetime2 with babel or polyglossia, make sure you load babel/ polyglossia before you load datetime2 otherwise their \date〈language〉 will overwrite \datetime’s definition of \today.
>   Additionally you need to make sure you install the relevant datetime2 language modules.

Thanks for your help and any ideas!

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}`?

Comment: Indeed, that works. Can you explain why this is necessary? Did I just missed this in the documentation? (Thanks for the nice package btw!)

Comment: (Thanks!) Yes, it is documented :-) The default is to use the non-locale style. (Chapter 6, two paragraphs down from your quote: "By default `useregional` is false, unless the language/ region is passed via the datetime2 package option list. ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of `datetime2` is to use the numeric ISO style regardless of the document language. You can switch on the locale-sensitive date and time using one of the following methods:

- Use the package option `useregional` (or `useregional=text`) for textual dates and `useregional=numeric` (or `useregional=num`) for the locale-sensitive numeric style.
- Declare the locales in `datetime2`'s package option list. For example `\usepackage[de-DE-1996]{datetime2}`. (This is useful if the document language setting doesn't include the required region but the relevant `datetime2` language module supports it. For example, `\usepackage[en-IE]{datetime2}`, which uses GMT/IST time zones or `\usepackage[en-GG]{datetime2}`, which uses CET/CEST time zones.)